# Python calling function from DLL (WinDLL)

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

*I trying a lot of methods, but any method work strange. Some return error, some return value, but not what I need to be returned ("0" rather than string).*

So, I try to use [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) in python code. I make example tool, but when I start using API I stacked. Simply I can't call function or call it wrong.

My code you may see on [Github](https://github.com/JumpJets/pysearch-on-Everything/commit/ba2acd2bff3c39ab88cb0e6b05777a28195a4b7e) (with comments).
To run it need dll, that you can also find on Github, Everything itself and python 3.5.
Run it in cmd by using command: `fs [path]` (i.e. `C:\`, but not used right now as I can't call function)

Code started at line 73 and ended at 126.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than struggling with calling "Everything" I would suggest that you take a look at the python built-in library functions `os.walk`, `fnmatch.fnmatch` and `glob.glob` - they work very well to do what everything does with no external dependencies and a simple pythonic user calling interface.

Additionally, if you write your code using them, you code will work on every platform that supports python.

Comment: Thanks for this info, I will test with it also. But about my code I do it for some reasons and some of it: learn how to write code for DLL, because I also have another libraries, that I may(?) use in future. Also I programming on C# and looking on C++ with CUDA, but just not have time right now. So, I can meet with it later and want it know now.